# Stacked Container Views in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a view that looks like this.

[image: Storyboard layout]
[image: View hierachy]

Container View 3&4 are stacked together on the far right. 
3rd container view is under the 4th container view. 
I want the views to be stacked, however the 3rd container view gets pushed down to the bottom below the 4th container view. 
Why is this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that despite removing the 3rd container view, my view was still not showing up.

I add to bring it to the front.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.fourthContainerView];
```